# Pan Gesture block normal touch event?

Tags: ios, ios7, touch, ios7.1

I added a Pan Gesture, and found that the original touch event does not work any more?

Is there a way to let Pan Gesture only intercept two fingers move?

Comment: @property(nonatomic) NSUInteger minimumNumberOfTouches

Answer (score 0):

```
//...
@interface MyViewController () 


//...
self.panGesture.delegate = self; 

//...
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}
```